# How to reimport labels into Stata

Tags: excel, stata, label

I'm currently trying to export data from Stata to excel (and make a pivot and a vlookup in excel) and then to reimport it into stata.

Everything works as expected except for Variables with a label are exported as follow "[1] very good" or without label "1" and imported as a string or in case 2 without a label.

Is there a way to reimport the variables in such a way that stata recognizes the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stata cannot import labels from an Excel file with the single -import excel- command.

However, you could import the labels as local macros from the Excel file if you did this right after your -import excel- command. Here is some example code I used for a project. If you give me more details on your specific instance (e.g. Excel file format), I can rewrite this code for your instance.

```
*Store variable names, types, labels, and value labels as locals
local opts clear allstring sheet("Variables") firstrow case(lower)
import excel "../docs/Variable names and values.xlsx", `opts'
forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    local varname = variablename[`i']       //variable name
    local `varname'lbl = variablelabel[`i'] //variable label
}

import delimited "../raw/NFP Baseline Survey.csv", case(lower) clear delim(",") varnames(1) stringcols(_all)

*Label variables
foreach v of varlist * {
    label variable `v' "``v'lbl'"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But after trying a little bit with excel and state I realized that I could simple paste entire columns to stata in the edit mode. Hence I just inserted the three columns I created in excel into stata and everything works fine! (That is because I neer changed the order of the values of a variable in excel. I think that could pose a problem)

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks for the follow up.

I was offering a more programmatic solution.